# ArcGIS Server 10.5 service conflicts with Remote Desktop login into Windows Server 2012 R2 machine

Tags: arcgis-server

We are in the process of migrating to ArcGIS Server 10.5 and stuck with a strange issue:

ArcGIS Server 10.5 is installed in Windows Server 2012 R2 (virtual machine). Whenever I try to remote login to that machine using Remote Desktop it takes at least 20 minutes to login. But if I remotely stop the ArcGIS Server Service or change the Log on as a different user/refresh the service it logs in to Remote Desktop right away.

Have anybody seen this behavior?

I am also facing supplementary problems which I don't want to list as this is the critical one to be solved first.
Also, here is a list of things which I tried and failed:
1. Log On as ArcGIS Server service using a domain account (which works fine in our ArcGIS Server 10.3 production environment) has slow login to Remote Server (using Remote Desktop). When remotely changed the Log on as ArcGIS Server service to local account(and refreshed), Remote Desktop immediately logs in to the Remote Server. So, I though it has something to do with domain account. 
2. Log On as ArcGIS Server service using a previous Local account again has slow login to Remote Server (using Remote Desktop). When remotely changed the Log on as ArcGIS Server service to local system account or domain account(and refreshed), Remote Desktop immediately logs in to the Remote Server. Now, it's clear that it has nothing to do with domain account or local account or local system account - but with ArcGIS Server 10.5. 
Any thoughts?

Comment: Just curious does the slowness to log in occur for every account or just the account running the ArcGIS Server processes?

Comment: unfortunately, every account- even local account and local system account

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug (BUG-000100522). In most instances I've seen this, it gets stuck on "applying group Policy". http://support.esri.com/bugs/nimbus/QlVHLTAwMDEwMDUyMg==

Comment: That bug report is for version 10.3?

Comment: Version found means the problem was first reported in ArcGIS Server 10.3.1. The bug is valid for Server 10.5 from what I understand.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer thru' Geonet forums. I am posting the extract of that answer for anybody to avoid going thru' the pain of installing ArcGIS Server 10.5 on a WS 2012 box:

ArcGIS Server 10.5 has conflict with Windows Server 2012 and 2012 R2 even though ESRI list it as a supported OS in system requirements.

So, workaround is to avoid both those versions of WS.

Source: A [tech bug report doc](http://support.esri.com/Technical-Article/000015494). hidden somewhere in ESRI website.

Worst part: ESRI didn't even care to add it to "[OS limitations](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/latest/os-limits-windows.htm)" section in [ArcGIS Server 10.5 System requirements](http://gis.com/en/server/latest/install/windows/arcgis-server-system-requirements.htm).

Great software deployment strategy!!!

See the original Geonet positing [here](https://geonet.esri.com/message/696845-re-arcgis-server-105-service-conflicts-with-remote-desktop-login-into-windows-server-2012-r2-machine?commentID=696845&et=watches.email.thread#comment-696845).